# Change OpenSSH account password in Linux

Tags: linux, security, ssh, openssh

I suppose that my main Linux user account password serves as my SSH password as well. Is there a way I can modify this? As it turns out, I'd like to have a REALLY secure SSH password for obvious reasons, but a less secure local password, as it makes typing in passwords a heck of a lot easier on a machine. Is there a way I can change my account password in SSH without changing my Linux user password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. But if you [use a SSH key](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-keyc.html) and require login using a key then you can set the key passphrase to anything you like.

Comment: Fyi, the linked page mostly describes generation of SSH1-RSA keys. Be careful with the instructions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look  into it. That's always more secure than using passwords anyway, right? Do you know of a tutorial on how to get key-only authentication set up on servers and clients?

Comment: Normally this is controlled by the `PasswordAuthentication` option in `sshd_config`; you can use `Match` to restrict it to specific users.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible with some PAM configuration magic. With SSH, however, key-based authentication as suggested by Ignacio is a better solution.